# How to refresh angular view depending on changes in c# code

Tags: c#, angular

I have developed an Angular application that consumes ASP.NET WebApi. 
I am using SQL Server Service Broker to be notified about changes in database, changes are made by external application.

```
using (var otherNotifier = new EntityChangeNotifier<Product, StoreDbContext>(x => x.Name == "Desk"))
{
    otherNotifier.Changed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Results.Count());
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop listening for changes...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

External API changes records in database and I am being notified correctly.
I am wondering if it's possible to refresh somehow a angular view when I detect changes.

Comment: You can achieve this through push notification. For the .NET applications, SignalR is the best framework but you can also achieve in web API just look this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/push-notification-in-web-application-using-web-api-and-pushcontentstream/) or look into [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/real-time)

Comment: I am interested in the simplest way as possible.

Comment: For the simplest way you need to create a get request on API and call it regularly from the angular app for checking updates

Comment: Do you need an example for that?

Comment: I need the simplest but calling API over and over will produce a lot of unwanted network traffic. Which one of the other options is the simplest?
Do push notifications are enough?

Comment: Push notifications are the way to go as polling the api is not a viable option in the long run

Comment: What about websocket? What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario, push notification via SignalR is the best way. There are several solutions to your problem.
I have given you [server sent event example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/push-notification-in-web-application-using-web-api-and-pushcontentstream/). 
The differences between SSE and Web Sockets both technologies are not that big and both are good choices. By far the biggest difference between both technologies is that WebSockets are full-duplex, bidirectional communication between client and server, whereas SSEs are mono-directional.

You can read the full article [here](https://www.scaledrone.com/blog/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-sses/)